# JQXGrid fixed(pinned) rows or toolbar/aggregates under header

Tags: jquery, header, jqxgrid, jquery-widgets

I'm making some kind of file manager using JQXGrid and I need to have a fixed(pinned) row in the top of the grid with the link "Go Back". Is there a way to insert a fixed row (not affected by sorting) or to move aggregates to the top under the header?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the Toolbar Feature of the Grid: [jqxGrid Toolbar](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/toolbar.htm?light)

Comment: Yes, but it is not under the header, it's on top of it.